# Javascript is setting var to early

Tags: javascript, var

I am learning since some days JavaScript but now I have the problem that I want to set a var always after a calculation to the Old value like this:

```
var Old = [0,0];
var New = [0,0];

test();

function test() {
  Old = New;
  New[0] = 0;
  New[1] = 5;

  alert(Old + " : " + New);

  do_some_calculation_stuff();
}
```

but i dont understand why the Old and New value is always instantly the same and how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because assigning an array like that means just assigning the reference. If you want to make a shallow copy of what is in `New`, you need to do something like:

`Old = New.slice(0);`

The above is essentially a short form for doing this:

```
Old = [];
for (var i = 0; i < New.length; ++i) {
    Old[i] = New[i]
}
```

Comment: Darnit. Beat me to it by like 10 seconds... :)

Comment: thank you very much, problem solved in under 5 min :D

Answer (score 1):

When you assign `New` to `Old`, you are actually just assigning it the reference to the Array. At that point, both variables are pointing to the exact same Object. If you modify the array by the reference `New`, it will also appear changed when accessed via `Old`